# NetworkX extra labels when drawing graph with subset of nodes and edges

Tags: python, graph, label, draw, networkx

I found a problem that I have not been able to reproduce.
I am currently working with a MultiDiGraph that I want to show only a portion of, the problem is that, when shown, I do not see only the nodes and edges that I selected, but also all of the labels in the graph.

I tried to recreate the error with something simple, as my original code is way to complex to explain.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

gr = nx.MultiDiGraph()
gr.add_nodes_from(["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4","192.168.1.5" ])
gr.add_edge("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", key=1)
gr.add_edge("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.3", key=2)
gr.add_edge("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.4", key=3)
gr.add_edge("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.5", key=4)
gr["192.168.1.1"]["192.168.1.2"][1]["color"] = 'b'
gr["192.168.1.1"]["192.168.1.3"][2]["color"] = 'b'
gr["192.168.1.1"]["192.168.1.4"][3]["color"] = 'b'
gr["192.168.1.1"]["192.168.1.5"][4]["color"] = 'b'

pos = nx.random_layout(gr)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))

n=["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4"]
e=[["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", 1], ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.3", 2], 
   ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.4", 3]]
colors = [gr[u][v][k]["color"] for u, v, k in e]

nx.draw_networkx(gr, with_labels=True, edge_color=colors, nodelist=n, edgelist=e)
```

This is the image I get, as expected:
[Functioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKNYh.png)
But in my code I get something like this (fraction of result):
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9j7B.png)

Does anybody has any idea why it does that?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you are asking here. I get the same thing as your `Functioning` image. What do you mean by "in your code" you get something else?

Comment: The functioning image does not show the error that i get with different data.
I was wondering if there was a bug or a feature for the draw_networkx function that makes it show all of the labels but not all of the nodes.

For example, if you add an edge in "e" connected to a node not present in "n", the function will draw the edge and add the label, but will not show the node.

And, if you add a node in "n" but not any edge, you will see the node with his label.

But i do not understand how i see the labels without any node or edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution myself for this, in case it happens to someone else, you can just draw nodes, edges and labels separately.

```
import networkx as nx
l = {node: node for node in n}

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_color='black', alpha=0.9, node_size=60, nodelist=n)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edge_color=colors, edgelist=e)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, font_size=8, font_color='black', labels=l)
```